# YouTube video regex in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have the following regular expression in PHP that verifies URLs of YouTube videos:

```php
preg_match('/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"\'>]+)/', $message)
```

I need to implement this same regular expression in MySQL, so that:

```
$posts = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM posts
    WHERE message REGEXP '^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"\'>]+)'
", $connection);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: [`RLIKE`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-rlike-function.php)

Comment: [REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: @tung If I run the regular expression in PHP it works correctly, but the MySQL query does not return any records. The error is of the regular exresión, since if for example I execute `WHERE message REGEXP 'youtube\.com'` it works.

Comment: Grab it from [here](https://regex101.com/r/yr2ppt/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much! It seems that it works.

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP '^(https?://)?(www[.])?(m[.])?(youtu[.]be/|youtube[.]com/((watch)?[?](.*&)?vi?=|(embed|v|vi|user)/))[^?&\"''>]+'
```

The point is:

- Replace all non-capturing groups to capturing
- Do not escape `/` as they are not special regex metacharacters
- It is easier to use `[]` around single chars in case you are not sure how they should be escaped
- To define a single quote you need to use double single quote in a MySQL string literal.